# SQL Server R Services error invalid input in 'utf8towcs'

Tags: sql-server, r, microsoft-r

Trying to run an R procedure in-database with Microsoft SQL Server R Services via `sp_execute_external_script`, but I receive this error even if I reduce my R script to do nothing but return an empty data frame.

```
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of '' 
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
An external script error occurred: 
Error in sort.list(y) : invalid input 'BiototÆs spots' in 'utf8towcs'
Calls: as.data.frame ... as.data.frame -> as.data.frame.character -> factor -> sort.list

Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
Execution halted
```

The error appears when special characters are included in the results of the input query in a column of type `varchar`, but I cannot use to the typical R tricks to re-encode character data during the data frame creation because the transformation of the `@input_data_1` query result to the `InputDataSet` data frame occurs outside of the control of the procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the string data to unicode before it is passed to R. You can do this by casting the `varchar` columns as `nvarchar` in the input query to match the expected encoding for input to the data frame conversion.

```
SELECT CAST(ColA AS nvarchar(255)) FROM TableA
```